# how to remove asp.net webforms tag from visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

when i write mockup in visual studio i found in intellesense  that some tags like

asp:tagname but in mvc i don't want it. so are i can remove it then when i write mock up then i not see this webform tags in intellesense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this one:

[Modifying IntelliSense Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1.aspx)

It's not possible to turn IntelliSense off just for ASP.NET MVC. If you turn it off you won't get IntelliSense for all sets of tags.